# Generic Type 'Props' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to Typescript, and I'm trying to figure out what is happening exactly, and why. I've updated typescript dependency for the project, from 4.7.4 to the newest 4.8.4 version, and I'm getting errors for components, that are using generic props.

Example:

```
export const withSomething = function <Props>(Component: FunctionComponent<Props>): FunctionComponent<Props> {
    const WithSomething = function (props: Props) {
        return <Component {...props} />
    };

    return WithSomething;
};
```

I removed any real logic from example, originally it was wrapping the component in some additional provider. *Props* are generic. This code was working perfectly fine with typescript version 4.7.4. But for 4.8.4 I'm getting following errors:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Props' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
  Type 'Props' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

```
export const withSomething = function <Props>(Component: FunctionComponent<Props>): FunctionComponent<Props> {
                                       ~~~~~
This type parameter might need an `extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` constraint.
```

Now, maybe I don't know what to look at exactly, but for me there is nothing in *react* source, that forces *Props* of *FunctionComponent* to extend *JSX.IntrinsicAttributes*. I've spent couple of hours trying to find the cause, and for now I have no idea what is really happening. I also don't necessarily see anything in Typescript release notes that would explain this, but I probably don't understand enough from them.

I can simply extend *JSX.IntrinsicAttributes*, update all places that are using this code and it will probably work, but I'd like to know what is happening, and is this correct approach. After reading several topics, I'm quite sure that I'm missing something fairly obvious.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, you should add `extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` - Components now implicitly take JSX.IntrinsicAttributes *and* whatever attributes you define for them.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, IntrinsicAttributes only has the 'key' property, so you can just pass a key to Component and it'll compile. In theory it's a brittle solution but who knows when anything else will be added to that interface.

```
export const withSomething = function <Props>(Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props>): React.FunctionComponent<Props> {
    const WithSomething = function (props: Props) {
        return <Component {...props} key="ComponentWithSomething" />
    };

    return WithSomething;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but here are my thoughts.

Regardless of the fact that the `key` prop is optional in IntrinsicAttributes, it's still an object type. In fact `props` is always an object type

For instance:

```
// this fails:

const func2 = (someParam : {test?: string}) => someParam.test;

const func1 = <P, >(someParam: P) => func2(someParam);

// And this passes:

const func2 = (someParam : {test?: string}) => someParam.test;

const func1 = <P extends {}>(someParam: P) => func2(someParam);
```

I would change your code to:

```
export const withSomething = function <Props extends {} /* note this change*/>(Component: FunctionComponent<Props>): FunctionComponent<Props> {
    const WithSomething = function (props: Props) {
        return <Component {...props} />
    };

    return WithSomething;
};
```